# How to create and draw sprites in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have obtained an assignment where I need to create a game using emu8086.

But the problem is I don't know how to draw a sprite.

Can anyone help me by explaining sprite creation to me?

Comment: How to draw a sprite depends on where to draw a sprite. In other words, the specification of your device on which you want to draw a script is required.

Comment: Can you tell me how to draw on emu8086 ?

Comment: If emu8086 faithfully emulates an 8086 PC with the BIOS and supports CGA, EGA or VGA, you need to find information on how to program those in various graphic modes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can you tell me how to draw on emu8086 ?

First you setup a graphics video mode. Next code selects the 320x200 256-color mode:

```
mov     ax, 0013h  ; AH=00h is BIOS.SetVideoMode, AL=13h is 320x200 mode
int     10h
```

Now you can plot any pixel you like. Below is an example that plots a single pixel in the center of the screen:

```
mov     dx, 100    ; Y = 200 / 2
mov     cx, 160    ; X = 320 / 2
mov     bh, 0      ; DisplayPage
mov     ax, 0C02h  ; AH=0Ch is BIOS.WritePixel, AL=2 is color green
int     10h
```

To draw a line you repeat plotting a pixel while changing one or both coordinates. Below is an example that draws the vertical line (100,50) - (100,150). This line has 101 pixels (150 - 50 + 1):

```
    mov     bh, 0      ; DisplayPage doesn't change
    mov     cx, 100    ; X is fixed for a vertical line
    mov     dx, 50     ; Y to start
More:
    mov     ax, 0C04h  ; AH=0Ch is BIOS.WritePixel, AL=4 is color red
    int     10h
    inc     dx         ; Next Y
    cmp     dx, 150
    jbe     More
```

To plot an area you use a couple of nested loops. Below is an example that plots the rectangle between (200,33) - (209,35). This area has 30 pixels (209 - 200 + 1) * (35 - 33 + 1):

```
    mov     si, Bitmap
    mov     bh, 0      ; DisplayPage doesn't change
    mov     dx, 33     ; Y to start
OuterLoop:
    mov     cx, 200    ; X to start
InnerLoop:
    lodsb              ; Fetch color for this pixel
    mov     ah, 0Ch    ; AH=0Ch is BIOS.WritePixel
    int     10h
    inc     cx         ; Next X
    cmp     cx, 209
    jbe     InnerLoop
    inc     dx         ; Next Y
    cmp     dx, 35
    jbe     OuterLoop

    ...

Bitmap:                ; Just some blue and cyan pixels
    db      1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3
    db      3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1
    db      1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3
```