# Repeat instruction in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've created 3 squares that appear nice to the eye. I only want to repeat this animation over and over, I know it ain't hard but I can't find how to do so. The explanations are in Romanian, sorry for them.

Basically I just want to clear the screen and make them appear over and over. Thanks for all the support.

```
.stack 100
.data
y1 dw 70
x  dw 70
y2 dw 120

x2 dw 130
y3 dw 70
y4 dw 120

x3 dw 190
y5 dw 70
y6 dw 120

l db 50; lungime
k db 50;latime
kfinal db 51
n db 50

.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,0h
mov al,13h; comutare in modul grafic 13h (320 x 200)
int 10h

desen:
mov dx,y1
mov cx,x
mov al,1; culoare
mov bl,l; lungime linie
mov ah,0ch; scriere pixel, cu culoare in al, cx=x, dx=y
mov bh,0
ciclu1: int 10h ; aprindere pixel de coordonate (cx,dx)
push dx
mov dx,y2
call delay
call delay
call delay
call delay
int 10h
pop dx
inc cx
dec bl
jnz ciclu1
mov bl,k; latime

ciclu2: int 10h ; aprinde pixel de coord (cx,dx)
push cx
mov cx,x
call delay
call delay
call delay
call delay
int 10h
pop cx
inc dx
dec bl
jnz ciclu2
int 10h
mov dx,y3
mov cx,x2
mov al,14; culoare
mov bl,l; lungime linie
mov ah,0ch; scriere pixel, cu culoare in al, cx=x, dx=y
mov bh,0

ciclu3: int 10h ; aprindere pixel de coordonate (cx,dx)
push dx
mov dx,y4
call delay
call delay
call delay
call delay
int 10h
pop dx
inc cx
dec bl
jnz ciclu3
mov bl,k; latime
ciclu4: int 10h ; aprinde pixel de coord (cx,dx)
push cx
mov cx,x2
call delay
call delay
call delay
call delay
int 10h
pop cx
inc dx
dec bl
jnz ciclu4
int 10h
mov dx,y5
mov cx,x3
mov al,4; culoare
mov bl,l; lungime linie
mov ah,0ch; scriere pixel, cu culoare in al, cx=x, dx=y
mov bh,0

ciclu5: int 10h ; aprindere pixel de coordonate (cx,dx)
push dx
mov dx,y6
call delay
call delay
call delay
call delay
int 10h
pop dx
inc cx
dec bl
jnz ciclu5
mov bl,kfinal; latime ultimul patratel

ciclu6: int 10h ; aprinde pixel de coord (cx,dx)
push cx
mov cx,x3
call delay
call delay
call delay
call delay
int 10h
pop cx
inc dx
dec bl
jnz ciclu6
ret

delay:
push cx
mov cx, 0ffffh
et1: dec cx
jnz et1
pop cx
ret


mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some important observations

- What first strikes me is that you've complicated matters by not using descriptive names for the program variables! See below for some better names.

  > ```
  > y1 dw 70
  > x  dw 70
  > y2 dw 120
  >
  > x2 dw 130
  > y3 dw 70
  > y4 dw 120
  >
  > x3 dw 190
  > y5 dw 70
  > y6 dw 120
  > ```

  ```
  Box1Left    dw 70
  Box1Top     dw 70
  Box1Bottom  dw 120

  Box2Left    dw 130
  Box2Top     dw 70
  Box2Bottom  dw 120

  Box3Left    dw 190
  Box3Top     dw 70
  Box3Bottom  dw 120
  ```
- Although you've set your width and height both to 50 (`l db 50 ;lungime` `k db 50 ;latime`), the boxes that you draw have a surface of 51x51.
- Your 1st (blue) box and your 2nd (yellow) box use a different system than the 3rd (red) box when it comes to drawing the final LowerRightCorner dot. Why is that?
  Why use the extra variable `kfinal db 51` ?
- The code that draws the boxes ends with a `ret` instruction, yet it wasn't `call`-ed. This is wrong. Moreover the code that terminates to DOS is unreachable because it sits below another `ret` instruction.
- Instead of repeating the whole box drawing code 3 times, you should place it in a subroutine and have it `call`-ed 3 times.

  ```
      mov  al, 1        ; Blue
      mov  cx, Box1Left
      mov  dx, Box1Top
      mov  bp, Box1Bottom
      call DrawBox
      mov  al, 14       ; Yellow
      mov  cx, Box2Left
      mov  dx, Box2Top
      mov  bp, Box2Bottom
      call DrawBox
      mov  al, 4        ; Red
      mov  cx, Box2Left
      mov  dx, Box2Top
      mov  bp, Box2Bottom
      call DrawBox

      mov  ax, 4C00h    ; DOS.Terminate
      int  21h

  DrawBox:
      mov  ah, 0Ch      ; BIOS.WritePixel
      mov  bh, 0        ; DisplayPage
      push cx           ; (1)

      mov  bl, 50       ; Width = Length of the horizontal line
  ciclu1:
      int  10h
      xchg dx, bp
      int  10h
      xchg dx, bp
      inc  cx
      dec  bl
      jnz  ciclu1

      pop  bp           ; (1)
      mov  bl, 51       ; Height = Length of the vertical line
  ciclu2:
      int  10h
      xchg cx, bp
      int  10h
      xchg cx, bp
      inc  dx
      dec  bl
      jnz  ciclu2
      ret
  ```

---

### The answer to your question

> Basically I just want to clear the screen and make them appear over and over.

If this is all that you want then you simply need to restart your program. Your program already starts by clearing the screen because it sets video mode 13h.
Please give the user a chance to stop your program. See how I did it in below example code:

```
    mov  ax, @data
    mov  ds, ax

Again:
    mov  ah, 00h
    mov  al, 13h; comutare in modul grafic 13h (320 x 200)
    int  10h

    ; Here you draw the boxes! Use the above code snippet...

    mov  ah, 00h      ; BIOS.WaitKey Wait for the user to press any key
    int  16h          ; -> AX
    cmp  al, 27       ; Did the user press <ESC> ?
    je   Exit         ; Yes
    jmp  Again        ; No, restart the program (this could be a big jump)

Exit:
    mov  ax, 4C00h    ; DOS.Terminate
    int  21h

; All subroutines go here, below the Exit to DOS!
```

You can read more about drawing in this post
[How to create and draw sprites in emu8086?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937822/how-to-create-and-draw-sprites-in-emu8086/54974569#54974569)